# Why element is not available in directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

You have probably heard it as many times as I have. "Do all your DOM manipulation in directives". But no one ever seems to say what could happen if you actually do DOM manipulation outside a directive in Angular.

I have a problem that I managed to reproduce in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vc5FRwSFtDdHqL8X5akQ?p=preview)

I have made a very simple directive that just outputs the element to the console.

```
app.directive('dirre', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log({message:"dirrens linkFn", element: element, count: element.length})
    }
  }
});
```

I have two identical jquery UI accordions, the only difference is the way they are called. One is called in a controller and the other one in a directive. Calling accordion from a controller is of course something bad.

As you can see if you run the application there is a situation where one of the dirre-directives does not seem to have an element but there are no errors.

The same thing happens in a big application I'm working with right now. The problem seems to be that someone in our team decided to call Jquery UI's accordion in a controller and not in a directive.
I haven't been able to step through the code to see what actually happens but I strongly suspect that the DOM is modified while Angular is compiling and something goes wrong.
Is this a plausible explanation?

Is this an example of what can go wrong if you do DOM manipulations outside a directive?

Answer (score 0):

The controller and the directive links function are called asynchronously.
Usually you can see directives being built before the main Controller complete. When the controller terminates, the directives update their watched variable (ngModel, $watch(something)...). Basically this is done with promises.

The link/compile function however is not called again. You have to compile, watch, apply the new DOM. Which basically means writing the similar code to angularjs.

Comment: There is obviously something fishy going in the example I posted. The element is not available in the directory's link function as it should be. I'm not sure you are answering the question. Is the problem that the DOM manipulation of the accordion is interferring with some Angular process?

Comment: I don't believe what you are saying is right, when the page loads angular bootstraps itself and compiles the document which goes through all the nodes and executes the directives synchronously, the only case a directive link/compile function will be called asynchronously would be if it's using templateUrl to get the template.

'$watch' expressions are executed every '$digest' iteration, it has nothing to do with promises. To trigger a $digest a javascript event must have happened (user clicks an element, XHR response, etc.)

Comment: You are right, it is badly phrased. I didn't say link functions are asynchronous. I mean the maint Controller is started before the directive completes. They are not related. The #accordion is built in the Controller so the change won't be seen by the directives